# Powershell replace double quotes with single in a string

Tags: powershell

I just can't get it right

The below statement throws an exception and I cannot get the correct format

```
$appendedQry = $appendedQry -replace "\"","'"
```

What would be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should be

```
$appendedQry = $appendedQry -replace '"',''''
```

Comment: Personally, I like `-replace '"',"'"`. ;)

Answer (score 6):

this because the escaping character is `

in the following a working example

```
$appendedQry = "`"asd"
echo $appendedQry
$appendedQry = $appendedQry -replace "`"", "'"
echo $appendedQry
```

Answer (score 0):

I was replacing all occurances of the string in a file, using command

```
powershell -Command "(gc c:\input.txt) -replace 'aaa', 'bbb' | Out-File c:\output.txt"
```

To replace double quotes I need to do some trick - use the variable:

```
$ToReplace = "\" + """"
$command = "(gc c:\input.txt) -replace '" + $ToReplace + "', 'bbb' | Out-File c:\output.txt"
powershell -Command $command
```